# Why is 7-bit ASCII string literal encoded as UTF-8 in Ruby

Tags: ruby, encoding

I'm reading "The Ruby Programming Language". In section 3.2.6.1, "Multibyte characters in Ruby 1.9", the book introduces an optimization in Ruby's string

> If a string literal contains only 7-bit ASCII characters, then its encoding method will return ASCII, even if the source encoding is UTF-8

I tried the following simple script on both ruby 1.9.1-p431, 1.9.2 and 1.9.3-p125, both uses UTF-8 encoding for 7-bit ASCII characters.

```
# coding: utf-8
s = 'hello'
p s.encoding
# result is #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

I guess maybe this behavior is changed during the development of Ruby 1.9. I tried to search Ruby 1.9's changelog, and the [1.9.1 changelog](http://svn.ruby-lang.org/repos/ruby/tags/v1_9_1_0/ChangeLog) confirms this behavior. I also cloned Ruby's git repository but I can't find the commit mentioning about changing this behavior.

**Update:**

Looking at Ruby's source code repository, I guess this is the behavior in Ruby 1.9.0, which was released in Jan, 2008. (It failed to compile on Debian 6 so I can't exactly confirm this.) **Though "The Ruby Programming Language" is an excellent book, it's originally published in 2008. It's very likely that some descriptions in the book are outdated.**

Another outdated description is about the `Encoding.list` method behavior. So be careful of outdated description if you are also reading this book.

Comment: Just curious: How do 7-bit ASCII and UTF-8 encoded string containing only ASCII characters differ?

Comment: If you're curious, use `s.bytes` to inspect. By definition, though, 7-bit characters are stored in UTF-8 without modification.

Comment: If the string's encoding is set to UTF-8, then indexing using `[]` has to traverse the string from the beginning. If this setting to ASCII-8BIT optimization is removed, I guess there maybe other optimizations to avoid this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have that book, but The current Pdf version of the Programming Ruby book (the pickaxe) states

> String literals are always encoded using the encoding of the source file that contains them, regardless of the content of the string

And then gives an example where `"dog"` gains the utf-8 encoding. Looks like the edition of the book you have is wrong. Whether that was an errata in the print version of your book  or just the fact that ruby changed after it was printed, I don't know

Comment: Maybe the behavior has changed. I'll try to download Ruby 1.9.1 and try that script again.

Answer (score 2):

It's important to note that "encoding" in Ruby often refers to "interpretation" more than the actual bytes stored. When it says the encoding is UTF-8, that means that the bytes in that string will be interpreted as UTF-8 multi-byte characters, though given that UTF-8 is backwards-compatible with 7-bit ASCII by design, there is no obvious difference on the binary level.

Ruby does not automatically detect the encoding of your strings as there isn't a standard or even reliable method for determining this. This is why the default encoding method is applied to all strings unless explicitly specified when created or converted.

You can switch the encoding of the string without actually modifying the stored bytes using `force_encoding`. You can also convert to a different format, potentially re-mapping the stored bytes, using `encode`.

If you want to know more about the internals of a string you have several methods to explore:

```
'dog'.encoding
# => #<Encoding:UTF-8> 
'dog'.bytes.to_a
# => [100, 111, 103] 
'dog'.chars.to_a
# => ["d", "o", "g"]
```

Compare with a non 7-bit ASCII string:

```
'døg'.encoding
# => #<Encoding:UTF-8> 
'døg'.bytes.to_a
# => [100, 195, 184, 103]
'døg'.chars.to_a
# => ["d", "ø", "g"]
```

Comment: I understand the relationship between the underlying bytes and interpretation of bytes to characters. It's just that the description in the book does not match with current Ruby's implementation. Looking at Ruby's source code shows that it did set the encoding of 7-bit ASCII string to ASCII-8BIT in the past, maybe at Ruby 1.9.0 but I failed to compile that version on Debian 6. I can't find when the behavior changed to current one.